# Show progressbar of python script execution with nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I'm launching a python script like this with nodejs :

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var spw = cp.spawn('python', ['tql.py']),


spw.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});

spw.on('close', function (code) {
   console.log("Script ended");
});

spw.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Knowing that this code is inside a javascript file that is included in an html page and there is a `progressbar` element inside it, is there a way to update the `progressbar` according to the time of execution of the python script ?

Comment: execSync means "do it synchronous" so you have to wait for the end to get theoutput, probably you could check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/spawn-async

Comment: Just want to make this clear - you cannot use javascript running in a web page to execute things on the server. The script above will run on the server using node, right? So you can hook up the `data` events with something like websockets or server-sent events to interact with a progress element in the web browser.

Comment: Yes, it's on the server side. So do I have to define my own datas on the python script to define how to progress the bar ?