# It is possible to get the progress of a spawned process from nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, child-process

I'm spawning `npm install -g create-react-app` from a `js` script. I want to know if it's possible to get the progress of the installation using `spawn`.

```
const npmExecutable = /^win/.test(process.platform) ? "npm.cmd" : "npm";
const npm = spawn(npmExecutable, ["install", "-g", "create-react-app"]);
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541572/show-progress-on-node-js-child-process-exec) about using:

```
npm.on("message", data => {
  console.log(`A message: ${data}`);
});
```

but it does not show anything.

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802895/show-progressbar-of-python-script-execution-with-nodejs), about knowing the progress of a `python` script, but it does not have any answers.

Does someone of you have tried something like that or know any clue about this?

Comment: You probably want to use `npm.stdout.on('data', ...)`. The `child_process.on('message', ...)`  event is for a process with an IPC channel, which is generally a child process created using `child_process.fork(...)`.

Comment: Oh thanks. Now I can read the data, but what it shows is the _final output_ from the _npm command_, and not the progress of the execution of the command indeed, and that is what I really need.

Comment: You will need to process the output of the program to determine it's progress, there is no built in progress monitor for a process.

Comment: Yes, but ... what you mean by saying: _process the output of the program to determine it's progress_ ?

Comment: According to the [`npm config`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#progress) documentation you can listen to `stderr` to get the progress information. It says that `stderr` must be a `TTY`, I don't know what that means or how to parse the data, but that is where you will want to look.