# How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, fs

How do I download a file with Node.js **without using third-party libraries**?

I don't need anything special. I only want to download a file from a given URL, and then save it to a given directory.

Comment: "I only want to download a file from a given url, and then save it to a given directory," it seems pretty clear. :)

Comment: Joseph is making an incorrect assertion that all node processes are server processes

Comment: @lededje What prevents a server process from downloading a file and saving it to a directory on a server? It is prefectly doable.

Comment: Note that as of Node 18, `fetch` is built in and no third party libraries or hand-rolled code involving caching data chunks or pipes is necessary anymore.

Answer (score 902, accepted):

As of Node 18, you can use [the built-in `fetch` global](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/globals.html#fetch), which implements [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples) to download data with several methods built in to directly work with the result as plain text, JS-converted-from-JSON, or binary data (as ArrayBuffer).

For older versions of Node, you can create an HTTP `GET` request and pipe its `response` into a writable file stream:

```
const http = require('http'); // or 'https' for https:// URLs
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
const request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
   response.pipe(file);

   // after download completed close filestream
   file.on("finish", () => {
       file.close();
       console.log("Download Completed");
   });
});
```

If you want to support gathering information on the command line--like specifying a target file or directory, or URL--check out something like [Commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/).

More detailed explanation in https://sebhastian.com/nodejs-download-file/

Comment: I got the following console output when I ran this script: `node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:637:18)
`.

Comment: Try using a different URL on the `http.get` line; maybe `http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg` (and replace `file.png` with `file.jpg`).

Comment: Why would this error occur in the first place? The image is still online (http://im.glogster.com/media/2/5/24/10/5241033.png), so why does it produce an error? I'm still confused.

Comment: I thought perhaps you were on a network that was blocking access to that domain; the error message by itself wasn't really much to go on, so I took a guess. :)

Comment: My network isn't blocking access to that domain - I'm able to access it from my web browser (Google Chrome), but I can't access it from node.js using the method above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried the code again just now using both Node v0.8.5 and also Node v0.8.16 with no issues--I'm not sure why your connection is being refused, but I don't believe it has anything to do with Node specifically.

Comment: Someone who actually explains whats going on thank you, I saw this code so many time but for somereason your answer made the most sense

Comment: Does this code close the file properly when the script ends or would it lose data?

Comment: "Something went wrong" is saved into the file when I try this

Comment: @quantumpotato Take a look at the response you're getting back from your request

Comment: @jiehanzheng that aint just any ol cat! Thats keyboard cat! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J---aiyznGQ

Comment: This depends upon the req url type if you are requesting `https` you must use `https` otherwise it will throw error.

Comment: it there any method to get its progress. how much it is downloaded

Comment: This code does not properly close the fs write.  It is not noticable on very small files but it is definitely obvious on larger downloads.

Comment: @EthanKeiley why do you say that it isn't closed properly? By default `createWriteStream` will set `autoClose` to `true` and `readable.pipe` will call `end()` on the writeable when the readable ends.

Comment: For everyone that copied this function and nothing happend, or a file was created without getting it filled with more data than 0 kb: I had to do something with the file before it would be filled. For example, adding: `var unit_test_file_content = fs.readFileSync('/somedirectory//file.jpg');
 console.log(unit_test_file_content)` ensured the image actually got downloaded.

Comment: so any news on this ? I get "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443"

Comment: @steinybot This will eventually close... but if you immediately depend on the file existing, this won't work.

Comment: Can someone please provide a code snippet for how to do this async? Using async and await?

Comment: no 404 and a funny demo image? W in the chat.

Answer (score 588):

Don't forget to handle errors! The following code is based on Augusto Roman's answer.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
};
```

Comment: @vince-yuan is `download()` itself `pipe`able?

Comment: @theGrayFox Because the code in this answer is way longer than the accepted one. :)

Comment: @VinceYuan the callback is confusing me. if I now invoke `download()`, how would I do it? What would I place as the `cb` argument? I have the `download('someURI', '/some/destination', cb)` but don't understand what to put in the cb

Comment: @Abdul Sounds like you are very new to node.js/javascript. Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm It's not complex.

Comment: Great script.But when the file list is long, a error happens: Too many open files in system

Comment: @Abdul maybe it would be good if you share with the rest of the class what you have figured out ?

Comment: Is there a way to see the speed of the download? Like can track how many mb/s? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is an up-to-date solution. I don't see anything about  `close` being async and taking a callback in the node docs.

Comment: Looks like the right way to do this is with `end` now. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2950#issuecomment-278094170

Comment: can we specify the destination folder?

Comment: fs.unlink(dest) throws if not passing it a second argument (a callback) node v10.15.0

Comment: Other than handling errors, it is still necessary to check status code in response before saving the file `response.statusCode == 200`

Comment: when the url is invalid it might throw an `"ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK"` error due to the `fs.unlink` function requiring a function as its second argument. this can easily be fixed through adding another function as an argument after the path variable, e.g. `fs.unlink(dest, function(){console.log('error. unlinking...')})`

Answer (score 178):

As Michelle Tilley said, but with the appropriate control flow:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);
    });
  });
}
```

Without waiting for the `finish` event, naive scripts may end up with an incomplete file.

**Edit:** Thanks to @Augusto Roman for pointing out that `cb` should be passed to `file.close`, not called explicitly.

Comment: the callback is confusing me. if I now invoke `download()`, how would I do it? What would I place as the `cb` argument? I have the `download('someURI', '/some/destination', cb)` but don't understand what to put in the cb

Comment: @Abdul You specify the callback with a function only if you need to do something when the file has been successfully fetched.

Comment: It would be good to check the status code before saving: `response.statusCode == 200`

Answer (score 93):

Speaking of handling errors, it's even better listening to request errors too. I'd even validate by checking response code. Here it's considered success only for 200 response code, but other codes might be good.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');

const download = (url, dest, cb) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);

    const request = http.get(url, (response) => {
        // check if response is success
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return cb('Response status was ' + response.statusCode);
        }

        response.pipe(file);
    });

    // close() is async, call cb after close completes
    file.on('finish', () => file.close(cb));

    // check for request error too
    request.on('error', (err) => {
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });

    file.on('error', (err) => { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });
};
```

Despite the relative simplicity of this code, I would advise to use the [request module](https://github.com/request/request) as it handles many more protocols (hello HTTPS!) which aren't natively supported by `http`.

That would be done like so:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

const download = (url, dest, cb) => {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    const sendReq = request.get(url);
    
    // verify response code
    sendReq.on('response', (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return cb('Response status was ' + response.statusCode);
        }

        sendReq.pipe(file);
    });

    // close() is async, call cb after close completes
    file.on('finish', () => file.close(cb));

    // check for request errors
    sendReq.on('error', (err) => {
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });

    file.on('error', (err) => { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest, () => cb(err.message)); // delete the (partial) file and then return the error
    });
};
```

**EDIT**:

To make it work with `https`, change

```
const http = require('http');
```

to

```
const http = require('https');
```

Comment: The request module just works straight for HTTPs. Cool!

Comment: @ventura yep, btw, there's also the native [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) module that now can handle secure connections.

Comment: It's more error prone without a doubt. Anyway, in any case where using request module is an option, I'd advise it as it's way higher level and thus, easier and efficient.

Comment: @Buzut Your request code calls callback twice for success. Once on 'request' and once on 'finish' of file. Usual callback expectation is to be called once.

Comment: @Alex, nope, this is an error message and there's a return. So if `response.statusCode !== 200` the cb on `finish` will never be called.

Comment: It calls `finish` callback when status is 403, for me. Maybe you only want to start piping when response code is confirmed to be 200

Comment: Thank you for showing example using request module.

Comment: This code should definitely only start piping once the response have been confirmed to be a 200.

Comment: shouldn't the file stream close on all events (request.finish, request.error, file.finish, etc)?

Comment: I get `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"` when downloading from `https` link. `http` link works fine

Comment: Using `request` is a stable solution. Unfortunately this amazing package has been deprecated (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) as alternative solution: `node-fetch` => https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Answer (score 52):

gfxmonk's answer has a very tight data race between the callback and the `file.close()` completing.  `file.close()` actually takes a callback that is called when the close has completed.  Otherwise, immediate uses of the file may fail (very rarely!).

A complete solution is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
  });
}
```

Without waiting for the finish event, naive scripts may end up with an incomplete file. Without scheduling the `cb` callback via close, you may get a race between accessing the file and the file actually being ready.

Comment: What for are you storing request into a variable?

Comment: he "stores" it into a variable so it does not become a global variable by default.

Comment: @philk how do you know a global variable is created if `var request =` is removed?

Comment: You are right, there is no need to save the request, its not used anyway. That's what you mean?

Comment: @philk thank you. Yes, I think that's what [polkovnikov.ph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1872046/polkovnikov-ph) meant.

Answer (score 30):

Maybe node.js has changed, but it seems there are some problems with the other solutions (using node v8.1.2):

1. You don't need to call `file.close()` in the `finish` event. Per default the `fs.createWriteStream` is set to autoClose: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options
2. `file.close()` should be called on error. Maybe this is not needed when the file is deleted (`unlink()`), but normally it is: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options
3. Temp file is not deleted on `statusCode !== 200`
4. `fs.unlink()` without a callback is deprecated (outputs warning)
5. If `dest` file exists; it is overridden

Below is a modified solution (using ES6 and promises) which handles these problems.

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

function download(url, dest) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, { flags: "wx" });

        const request = http.get(url, response => {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                response.pipe(file);
            } else {
                file.close();
                fs.unlink(dest, () => {}); // Delete temp file
                reject(`Server responded with ${response.statusCode}: ${response.statusMessage}`);
            }
        });

        request.on("error", err => {
            file.close();
            fs.unlink(dest, () => {}); // Delete temp file
            reject(err.message);
        });

        file.on("finish", () => {
            resolve();
        });

        file.on("error", err => {
            file.close();

            if (err.code === "EEXIST") {
                reject("File already exists");
            } else {
                fs.unlink(dest, () => {}); // Delete temp file
                reject(err.message);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Two comments on this: 1) it should probably reject Error objects, not strings, 2) fs.unlink will quietly swallow errors which might not necessarily be what you want to do

Comment: This works great! And if your URLs use HTTPS, just substitute `const https = require("https");` for `const http = require("http");`

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fscreatewritestreampath-options) of `fs.createWriteStream()`: "If autoClose is set to true (default behavior) on 'error' or 'finish' the file descriptor will be closed automatically. " So no need to manually close the file on error.

Answer (score 21):

for those who came in search of  es6-style promise based way, I guess it would be something like:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

function pDownload(url, dest){
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var responseSent = false; // flag to make sure that response is sent only once.
    http.get(url, response => {
      response.pipe(file);
      file.on('finish', () =>{
        file.close(() => {
          if(responseSent)  return;
          responseSent = true;
          resolve();
        });
      });
    }).on('error', err => {
        if(responseSent)  return;
        responseSent = true;
        reject(err);
    });
  });
}

//example
pDownload(url, fileLocation)
  .then( ()=> console.log('downloaded file no issues...'))
  .catch( e => console.error('error while downloading', e));
```

Comment: `responseSet` flag caused, for some reason which I hadn't had the time to investigate, my file to be downloaded incompletely. No errors popped up but the .txt file I was populating had half of the rows that needed to be there. Removing the logic for the flag fixed it. Just wanted to point that out if someone had the issues with the approach. Still, +1

Answer (score 20):

Based on the other answers above and some *subtle* issues, here is my attempt.

1. Check the file does not exist before hitting the network by using `fs.access`.
2. Only create the `fs.createWriteStream` if you get a `200 OK` status code. This reduces the amount of `fs.unlink` commands required to tidy up temporary file handles.
3. Even on a `200 OK` we can still possibly `reject` due to an `EEXIST` file already exists (imagine another process created the file whilst we were doing network calls).
4. Recursively call `download` if you get a `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Found (Moved Temporarily)` redirect following the link location provided in the header.
5. The issue with some of the other answers recursively calling `download` was that they called `resolve(download)` instead of `download(...).then(() => resolve())` so the `Promise` would return before the download actually finished. This way the nested chain of promises resolve in the correct order.
6. It might seem *cool* to clean up the temp file asynchronously, but I chose to reject only after that completed too so I know that everything start to finish is done when this promise resolves or rejects.

```js
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Download a resource from `url` to `dest`.
 * @param {string} url - Valid URL to attempt download of resource
 * @param {string} dest - Valid path to save the file.
 * @returns {Promise<void>} - Returns asynchronously when successfully completed download
 */
function download(url, dest) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Check file does not exist yet before hitting network
    fs.access(dest, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {

        if (err === null) reject('File already exists');

        const request = https.get(url, response => {
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
       
              const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, { flags: 'wx' });
              file.on('finish', () => resolve());
              file.on('error', err => {
                file.close();
                if (err.code === 'EEXIST') reject('File already exists');
                else fs.unlink(dest, () => reject(err.message)); // Delete temp file
              });
              response.pipe(file);
            } else if (response.statusCode === 302 || response.statusCode === 301) {
              //Recursively follow redirects, only a 200 will resolve.
              download(response.headers.location, dest).then(() => resolve());
            } else {
              reject(`Server responded with ${response.statusCode}: ${response.statusMessage}`);
            }
          });
      
          request.on('error', err => {
            reject(err.message);
          });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't waste resources doing the download if the destination file already exists.  Do the check first if possible.

Comment: @Phil Really good point. I have updated the example with an earlier guard check before falling into the recursive networking calls but left the success 200 file handling code the same. This short circuit guard statement should save some time in this case now.

Comment: @JoshPeak what if the file is updated on server.

Comment: @y_159 Good question... This solution is only checking the name of the resource. If the file is different on the server then comparing modifed timestamps and hashes of content would be required conditions to invalidate the local cache. Correct cache invalidation is beyond the scope of this question and warrants it's own question and depends how servers implement HTTP ETag protocols.

Answer (score 19):

Hi，I think you can use **child_process** module and curl command.

```
const cp = require('child_process');

let download = async function(uri, filename){
    let command = `curl -o ${filename}  '${uri}'`;
    let result = cp.execSync(command);
};


async function test() {
    await download('http://zhangwenning.top/20181221001417.png', './20181221001417.png')
}

test()
```

In addition，when you want download large、multiple files，you can use **cluster** module to use more cpu cores.

Comment: This answer is super simple and easy. You can use `-L` flag at the end to make it follow redirect download (example from github.com).

Answer (score 17):

## Solution with timeout, prevent memory leak :

The following code is based on Brandon Tilley's answer :

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var request = http.get("http://example12345.com/yourfile.html", function(response) {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        var file = fs.createWriteStream("copy.html");
        response.pipe(file);
    }
    // Add timeout.
    request.setTimeout(12000, function () {
        request.abort();
    });
});
```

Don't make file when you get an error, and prefere to use timeout to close your request after X secondes.

Comment: this is only a file, has no protocol or server to download from... `http.get("http://example.com/yourfile.html",function(){})`

Comment: Is there a memory leak in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22793628/242933?

Comment: You can add timeout like I did in `http.get`. The memory leak is only if the file take too long to be downloaded.

Answer (score 10):

Modern version (ES6, Promise, Node 12.x+ ) works for https/http. ALso it supports redirects 302 & 301. I decided do not use 3rd party libraries due to it can be easy done with standard Node.js libs.

```
// download.js
import fs from 'fs'
import https from 'https'
import http from 'http'
import { basename } from 'path'
import { URL } from 'url'

const TIMEOUT = 10000

function download (url, dest) {
  const uri = new URL(url)
  if (!dest) {
    dest = basename(uri.pathname)
  }
  const pkg = url.toLowerCase().startsWith('https:') ? https : http

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = pkg.get(uri.href).on('response', (res) => {
      if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, { flags: 'wx' })
        res
          .on('end', () => {
            file.end()
            // console.log(`${uri.pathname} downloaded to: ${path}`)
            resolve()
          })
          .on('error', (err) => {
            file.destroy()
            fs.unlink(dest, () => reject(err))
          }).pipe(file)
      } else if (res.statusCode === 302 || res.statusCode === 301) {
        // Recursively follow redirects, only a 200 will resolve.
        download(res.headers.location, dest).then(() => resolve())
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Download request failed, response status: ${res.statusCode} ${res.statusMessage}`))
      }
    })
    request.setTimeout(TIMEOUT, function () {
      request.abort()
      reject(new Error(`Request timeout after ${TIMEOUT / 1000.0}s`))
    })
  })
}

export default download
```

Kudo to **Andrey Tkachenko** for his [gist](https://gist.github.com/falkolab/f160f446d0bda8a69172) which I modified

Include it in another file and use

```
const download = require('./download.js')
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/replace-this-with-your-remote-file'
console.log('Downloading ' + url)

async function run() {
  console.log('Downloading file')
  try {
    await download(url, 'server')
    console.log('Download done')
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Download failed')
    console.log(e.message)
  }
}

run()
```

Comment: Awesome. Very clean, thank you. What do the flags 'wx' do when you're creating the writeStream?

Comment: 'wx': Like 'w' but fails if the path exists.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer request() because you can use both http and https with it.

```
request('http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('cat.jpg'))
```

Comment: Looks like Request has been deprecated https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142  

`"As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are expected to land. In fact, none have landed for some time."`

Answer (score 8):

**Late 2022 edit**:

Node v18 and on come with [native Fetch API support](https://blog.logrocket.com/fetch-api-node-js/) built right into Node itself. No need for third party libraries or small hand-crafted shims, just use `fetch` the way you're used to from the browser.

(I.e. the second code block, below, does not need the `` const fetch = require(`./that-code-shown-above.js`); `` line anymore, `fetch` already exists globally)

**Original answer:**

For Node with `Promise` support, a simple Node shim for (part of) the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) requires only a smattering of extra code, rather than needing to install any special modules:

```js
const http = require(`http`);
const https = require(`https`);

module.exports = function fetch(url) {
  // we're returning a promise, so this function can also be `await`ed
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = [];
    // make sure we use the correct protocol handler
    const client = url.startsWith("https") ? https : http;
    client
      .request(url, (conn) => {
        // aggregate the response stream into a single string.
        conn.on(`data`, (chunk) => data.push(chunk));
        conn.on(`end`, () => {
          // make sure to encode that string using utf8
          const asBytes = Buffer.concat(data);
          const asString = asBytes.toString(`utf8`);
          // and then trigger the resolution, with the
          // most frequently used fetch API "follow-up"
          // functions:
          resolve({
            arrayBuffer: async () => asBytes,
            json: async () => JSON.parse(asString),
            text: async () => asString,
          });
        });
        conn.on(`error`, (e) => reject(e));
      })
      .end();
  });
};
```

Which you can then use for whatever you need, using the normal fetch syntax you're used to from the browser:

```js
const fs = require(`fs`);

// As per the note above: remove the following line for Node 18 and above
const fetch = require(`./that-code-shown-above.js`);

fetch(`https://placekitten.com/200/300`)
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(bytes => fs.writeFileSync(`kitten.jpg`, bytes))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));

try {
  const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

// etc.
```

Comment: would be nice if you could show how to actually use the built in fetch module to download files, your link does not say (and trying to google answers only leads to outdated / 3rd party things)

Comment: Why? It's the same Fetch API as found documented on MDN (already linked in the post), and the second code block _literally shows you how to download a file_ (a kitten picture, even) so I don't know what you think is still missing here =)

Answer (score 7):

Vince Yuan's code is great but it seems to be something wrong.

```
function download(url, dest, callback) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(callback); // close() is async, call callback after close completes.
        });
        file.on('error', function (err) {
            fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
            if (callback)
                callback(err.message);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: can we specify the destination folder?

Answer (score 7):

```
const download = (url, path) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
http.get(url, response => {
    const statusCode = response.statusCode;

    if (statusCode !== 200) {
        return reject('Download error!');
    }

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    response.pipe(writeStream);

    writeStream.on('error', () => reject('Error writing to file!'));
    writeStream.on('finish', () => writeStream.close(resolve));
});}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 7):

> ✅So if you use [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_source_transforms_destination_callback), it would close all other streams and make sure that there are no memory leaks.
>
> Working example:
>
> ```
> const http = require('http');
> const { pipeline } = require('stream');
> const fs = require('fs');
>
> const file = fs.createWriteStream('./file.jpg');
>
> http.get('http://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952', response => {
>   pipeline(
>     response,
>     file,
>     err => {
>       if (err)
>         console.error('Pipeline failed.', err);
>       else
>         console.log('Pipeline succeeded.');
>     }
>   );
> });
> ```

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459320/5732327) to ["What's the difference between .pipe and .pipeline on streams"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58875655).

Answer (score 7):

## Using the http2 Module

I saw answers using the **http**, **https**, and **request** modules. I'd like to add one using yet another native NodeJS module that supports either the http or https protocol:

### Solution

I've referenced the official NodeJS API, as well as some of the other answers on this question for something I'm doing. The following was the test I wrote to try it out, which worked as intended:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as _path from 'path';
import * as http2 from 'http2';

/* ... */

async function download( host, query, destination )
{
    return new Promise
    (
        ( resolve, reject ) =>
        {
            // Connect to client:
            const client = http2.connect( host );
            client.on( 'error', error => reject( error ) );

            // Prepare a write stream:
            const fullPath = _path.join( fs.realPathSync( '.' ), destination );
            const file = fs.createWriteStream( fullPath, { flags: "wx" } );
            file.on( 'error', error => reject( error ) );

            // Create a request:
            const request = client.request( { [':path']: query } );

            // On initial response handle non-success (!== 200) status error:
            request.on
            (
                'response',
                ( headers/*, flags*/ ) =>
                {
                    if( headers[':status'] !== 200 )
                    {
                        file.close();
                        fs.unlink( fullPath, () => {} );
                        reject( new Error( `Server responded with ${headers[':status']}` ) );
                    }
                }
            );

            // Set encoding for the payload:
            request.setEncoding( 'utf8' );

            // Write the payload to file:
            request.on( 'data', chunk => file.write( chunk ) );

            // Handle ending the request
            request.on
            (
                'end',
                () =>
                {
                    file.close();
                    client.close();
                    resolve( { result: true } );
                }
            );

            /* 
                You can use request.setTimeout( 12000, () => {} ) for aborting
                after period of inactivity
            */

            // Fire off [flush] the request:
            request.end();
        }
    );
}
```

Then, for example:

```
/* ... */

let downloaded = await download( 'https://gitlab.com', '/api/v4/...', 'tmp/tmpFile' );

if( downloaded.result )
{
    // Success!
}

// ...
```

**External References**

- https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_client_side_example
- https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_clienthttp2session_request_headers_options

**EDIT Information**

- The solution was written for typescript, the function a *class method* - but with out noting this the solution would not have worked for the presumed javascript user with out proper use of the `function` declaration, which our contributor has so promptly added. Thanks!

Comment: Is this backward compatible? Works everywhere or only for http2?

Comment: @Neil I'm assuming you are asking if http2 is backward compatible with http1.2 - and the answer is no.  Because http2 improves framing; adding binary compression, the ability to push from server to client, and simultaneous connections - it is absolutely required that both server and client know the implementation (this allows abstraction of implementation from the application too). Good news is that all major browsers have supported http2 since about 2015 - and Node as a client does too. Node, Nginx, and Apache offer it server side - so most use cases are covered. Its a vast improvement.

Answer (score 6):

**download.js** (i.e. /project/utils/download.js)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

const download = (uri, filename, callback) => {
    request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
        console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

module.exports = { download };
```

**app.js**

```
... 
// part of imports
const { download } = require('./utils/download');

...
// add this function wherever
download('https://imageurl.com', 'imagename.jpg', () => {
  console.log('done')
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Download using promise, which resolve a readable stream. put extra logic to handle the redirect.

```
var http = require('http');
var promise = require('bluebird');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');

function download(option) {
    assert(option);
    if (typeof option == 'string') {
        option = url.parse(option);
    }

    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = http.request(option, function(res) {
            if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(res);
            } else {
                if (res.statusCode === 301 && res.headers.location) {
                    resolve(download(res.headers.location));
                } else {
                    reject(res.statusCode);
                }
            }
        })
        .on('error', function(e) {
            reject(e);
        })
        .end();
    });
}

download('http://localhost:8080/redirect')
.then(function(stream) {
    try {

        var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('holyhigh.jpg');
        stream.pipe(writeStream);

    } catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: 302 is also HTTP status code for URL redirect, so you should use this [301,302].indexOf(res.statusCode) !== -1 in the if statement

Comment: The questions was specific to not include third party modes :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using express use res.download() method. otherwise fs module use.

```
app.get('/read-android', function(req, res) {
   var file = "/home/sony/Documents/docs/Android.apk";
    res.download(file) 
});
```

(or)

```
   function readApp(req,res) {
      var file = req.fileName,
          filePath = "/home/sony/Documents/docs/";
      fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
          if (exists) {     
            res.writeHead(200, {
              "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
              "Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=" + file});
            fs.createReadStream(filePath + file).pipe(res);
          } else {
            res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
            res.end("ERROR File does NOT Exists.ipa");
          }
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://github.com/douzi8/ajax-request#download

```
request.download('http://res.m.ctrip.com/html5/Content/images/57.png', 
  function(err, res, body) {}
);
```

Comment: It is returning garbage character if file name is other than ascii like if filename is in japanese.

Comment: Do you think `ajax-request` is not a third party library?

Answer (score 3):

## 2024 answer using async...await

Just use native `fetch` like:

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
   method: 'POST',
   body,
})
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
fs.writeFileSync(`file${i}.txt`, Buffer.from(buffer))
```

My route sent a `Response` like:

```js
return new Response(data, {
   headers: { 'content-type': 'application/text' },
})
```

so I used `Buffer.from` which you might or might not need depending on whether you want to download an image or text file.

Answer (score 1):

Path : img
type : jpg 
random uniqid

```
    function resim(url) {

    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var sayi = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000);
    var uzanti = ".jpg";
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("img/"+sayi+uzanti);
    var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});

        return sayi+uzanti;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without library it could be buggy just to point out. Here are a few:

- Can't handle http redirection, like this url https://calibre-ebook.com/dist/portable which is binary.
- http module can't https url, you will get `Protocol "https:" not supported.`

Here my suggestion:

- Call system tool like `wget` or `curl`
- use some tool like [node-wget-promise](https://github.com/ajhsu/node-wget-promise) which also very simple to use.

  `var wget = require('node-wget-promise');
  wget('http://nodejs.org/images/logo.svg');`

Answer (score 1):

Writing my own solution since the existing didn't fit my requirements.

**What this covers:**

- HTTPS download (switch package to `http` for HTTP downloads)
- Promise based function
- Handle forwarded path (status 302)
- Browser header - required on a few CDNs
- Filename from URL (as well as hardcoded)
- Error handling

It's typed, it's safer. Feel free to drop the types if you're working with plain JS (no Flow, no TS) or convert to a `.d.ts` file

index.js

```
import httpsDownload from httpsDownload;
httpsDownload('https://example.com/file.zip', './');
```

httpsDownload.[js|ts]

```
import https from "https";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";

function download(
  url: string,
  folder?: string,
  filename?: string
): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https
      .request(url, { headers: { "User-Agent": "javascript" } }, (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode === 302 && response.headers.location != null) {
          download(
            buildNextUrl(url, response.headers.location),
            folder,
            filename
          )
            .then(resolve)
            .catch(reject);
          return;
        }

        const file = fs.createWriteStream(
          buildDestinationPath(url, folder, filename)
        );
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on("finish", () => {
          file.close();
          resolve();
        });
      })
      .on("error", reject);
    req.end();
  });
}

function buildNextUrl(current: string, next: string) {
  const isNextUrlAbsolute = RegExp("^(?:[a-z]+:)?//").test(next);
  if (isNextUrlAbsolute) {
    return next;
  } else {
    const currentURL = new URL(current);
    const fullHost = `${currentURL.protocol}//${currentURL.hostname}${
      currentURL.port ? ":" + currentURL.port : ""
    }`;
    return `${fullHost}${next}`;
  }
}

function buildDestinationPath(url: string, folder?: string, filename?: string) {
  return path.join(folder ?? "./", filename ?? generateFilenameFromPath(url));
}

function generateFilenameFromPath(url: string): string {
  const urlParts = url.split("/");
  return urlParts[urlParts.length - 1] ?? "";
}

export default download;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function download(url, dest, cb) {

  var request = http.get(url, function (response) {

    const settings = {
      flags: 'w',
      encoding: 'utf8',
      fd: null,
      mode: 0o666,
      autoClose: true
    };

    // response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest, settings));
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest, settings);
    response.pipe(file);

    file.on('finish', function () {
      let okMsg = {
        text: `File downloaded successfully`
      }
      cb(okMsg);
      file.end(); 
    });
  }).on('error', function (err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    let errorMsg = {
      text: `Error in file downloadin: ${err.message}`
    }
    if (cb) cb(errorMsg);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
    request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);

    }); 
};   

download('https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/19684/doge.png', 'icons/taskks12.png', function(){
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to handle it without 3rd party dependency and also searching for redirects:

```
        var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
            var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
            https.get(url, function(response) {
                if ([301,302].indexOf(response.statusCode) !== -1) {
                    body = [];
                    download(response.headers.location, dest, cb);
                  }
              response.pipe(file);
              file.on('finish', function() {
                file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
              });
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way to do this:

```
async function archive_fromURL(url: string, destinationPath: string) {

    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    const fileData = Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary')
    return fs.writeFile(destinationPath, fileData, (err) => {
        if (err) { console.log("ErrorMessage:", err.message) }
    })

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `res.redirect` to the https file download url, and then it will be downloading the file.

Like: `res.redirect('https//static.file.com/file.txt');`

Answer (score -3):

I've found this approach to be the most helpful especially when it comes to pdfs and random other files.

```js
import fs from "fs";

  fs.appendFile("output_file_name.ext", fileDataInBytes, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("File saved!");
  });
```

Comment: I guess this is will work if you wish to save file, but question is about to download

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you to use `res.download` same as follow:

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  const file = `${__dirname}/folder/abc.csv`;
  res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```

Answer (score -5):

```
var requestModule=require("request");

requestModule(filePath).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('abc.zip'));
```

Comment: Code dumps are generally not useful and may be downvoted or deleted. It would be worth editing to at least explain what the code is doing for future visitors.