# Move files with node.js

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have a file "*/tmp/sample.txt*" and I want to move it to "*/var/www/mysite/sample.txt*" which is in a different volume.

How can i move the file in node.js?

I read that *fs.rename* only works inside the same volume and *util.pump* is already deprecated.

What is the proper way to do it? I read about stream.pipe, but I couldn't get it to work. A simple sample code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [mv module](https://npmjs.org/package/mv):

```
var mv = require('mv');

mv('source', 'dest', function(err) {
    // handle the error
});
```

Comment: is it possible to move the file from one server to another server?

Comment: my case was iterating through the songs deep inside folders and paste it in the root folder, I wrote all logic to find the songs and found this SO called **awesome** library `mv`. After the snippet has run in recursion, went to the `dest` folder and saw NOTHING and damn my `src` folder is also EMPTY, where the hell are my songs??? IMO: 1. Test it and use it. 2. Log what your doing, in my case these will help me download all songs :(

Answer (score 3):

If on Windows and don't have 'mv' module, can we do like

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    source = fs.createReadStream("c:/sample.txt"),
    destination = fs.createWriteStream("d:/sample.txt");

source.pipe(destination, { end: false });
source.on("end", function(){
    fs.unlinkSync("C:/move.txt");
});
```

Comment: @nha I meant without using mv if we want to do it. I tested the code on windows so..

Comment: +1 Thank you for the precision. I tested the `WriteStream` functions by piping streams into it (like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js ) and it worked fine. So did the rename function. But I had problems however using symlinks (I don't usually use windows).

Answer (score 2):

The mv module, like jbowes stated, is probably the right way to go, but you can use the child process API and use the built-in OS tools as an alternative. If you're in Linux use the "mv" command. If you're in Windows, use the "move" command.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('mv /temp/sample.txt /var/www/mysite/sample.txt', 
  function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    // stdout is a string containing the output of the command.
});
```

Comment: I'll stick with the mv module, but +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use spawn if exec doesn't work properly.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = spawn("mv", ["data.csv","./done/"]);
child.stdout.on("end", function () {                
    return next(null,"finished")
});
```

Hope this helps you out.