# Failed to add cordova android in ios 10.10.1 through terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, npm

When I am adding Android project using terminal I am getting the below error

Currently iOS project I can able to create but when I am creating Android its failing  to fetch 
fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz.
throws a error as Unable to fetch platform android: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.

I set the proxy already in terminal directly then only its created iOS but android it fails.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to manual download that file?

Comment: Yes through chrome I can able to download.

Comment: Try to use following code to download that file with node.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.My requirement is like a set of file and plugin sneed to be downloaded from cordova. Not a single file so I don't think this will help me.

Comment: I asked you to try it so that you will see that if it is cordova problem or network problem with node.

Comment: I am trying to run that comments but I am  not clear how to do that.

Comment: copy paste that code into download.js file and run node download.js in command line.

Comment: YES its downloaded a nice cat image. Thanks,,, what I can conclude in this. No issue with node? and cordova sit have issue? or..