# Force download from S3 on click

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have files stored on S3, and I want to automatically download them for a user when they click a button

What I've done so far is to have a route

/lib/routes/download

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

Router.route("download", function() {
  console.log('retrieving ' + this.params.signedURL);
  this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'appplication/pdf'}, this.params.signedURL);
  this.response.end(fs.readFileSync(this.params.signedURL));
}, { where: 'server', path: '/d/:signedURL'});
```

But this doesn't work, because i Cant use `fs` on the client. And even if I could, im not sure this would work

Any advice on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of adding a route, can you transmit the signed URL to the client via a method call?

Comment: Well I store them in my database if that's what you mean

Comment: If you have the signed URL already on the client, can't you just use the [download attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) of an anchor tag to accomplish this? Or are you trying to support non-HTML5 browsers?

Comment: I did that initially, but it has very poor browser support

Comment: So `readFileSync` takes a filename (not a url). I believe what your route needs to do is [download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js) and pipe the result back out to the client.

Comment: But I would much rather have the client do the downloading, is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to use the [cfs:s3 package](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/s3) which is an add-on to [CollectionFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages). This not only supports S3 but also transparently breaks files up into smaller chunks during upload and download to/from S3.

Answer (score 1):

I retrieve the signedUrl via a meteor method call, then do this when the user clicks a download button :

```
window.open(_signedURL,"_self");
```