# How can I save the link or images in our local directory inside D drive or F Drive through Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have some 3 or 5 a `href` links in `Node js`. Whenever I click those links the video will be download.

How can I save the video in our local directory inside D drive or F Drive through `Node JS`?

Answer (score 0):

To save/ download the videos from the links using nodejs you can use this code

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);
    });
  });
}
```

I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries) you can get more methods to do this.