# How to download a file from server to local sysytem desktop in node.js?

Tags: node.js, download

I have a file which I download to our desktop for all type of operating
system like windows, linux, mac etc. The below code I am using for download it from third server to my serve folder:

```
var fileticketID = req.params.fileticketID;
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
BASE.request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){BASE.request(uri).pipe(BASE.FS.createWriteStream('public/images/'+filename)).on('close', function(err) {
var stats = BASE.FS.statSync('public/images/'+filename);
var fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"];
var fields = {filename : filename,size:fileSizeInBytes};
var fieldsData = new downloadFile(fields);
fieldsData.save(function(err, data){
        if(!err)
        {
            if(fileSizeInBytes==0)
            {
                resMain.send('error');
            }
            else
            {
            resMain.send(filename);
            }
        //console.log('successfully saved -- ');
        }
        else
        {
            resMain.send('error');
        //console.log('sorry error ', err);
        }
    });
});
```

Now I want to file is also downloaded in desktop

Comment: I'm not very clear with the last sentence. "Now i want to file is also downloaded in desktop". What do you mean?

Comment: i want to download that file from server to local system

Comment: like if i have a file in my server folder http://example.com/images/filename then i want to download that file in local system desktop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: is there any way to get local system desktop path in node.js?

Comment: no that is different that is specific for directory but in my case i want to download it local system like c://desktop etc

Comment: You want to download the file from your local system or download the file to local system? If it is to local system, give the path to it when you download from browser. If it is from local system, your nodejs should be running from it and you can give absolute path to the file.

Comment: i want to download the file from server to local system

Comment: If that's the case, what @steady_daddy commented should work for you.