# Node.js - download and save PDF file locally for offline - file damaged

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pdf, node-webkit

I currently have a desktop App built with Node Webkit. When the user is online, the App will open up PDF files from the server. I then save these files locally so they are available when offline.

I am using the Node.js File System's fs.writeFile(), to save the PDF locally but when trying to open it via the App the PDF is blank. When I try to open it direct from the folder I get the below error.

[image]

Can anyone please advise?

```
//save PDF file for offline
function saveFile(pdfvar) {
    var filename = 'test.pdf';
    fs.writeFile(filename, pdfvar);
}

//open PDF in new window
$('#stage').on('click', '#pdflink', function(event){
    var pdfvar = (this.getAttribute('data-pdffile'));
    window.open(pdfvar, "_blank");
    if(online===true){
        saveFile(pdfvar);
    }
});
```

Comment: is your pdf getting rendered in new window??And add the error message.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the error!  yes, it opens a new window but the PDF doesn't load at all its just blank

Comment: It is happening because `pdfvar` does not contain a valid pdf file

Comment: it does contain a valid PDF file.  It opens fine when online, but doesn't open when saved locally, so something is happening when being saved.

Comment: Upload your PDF somewhere online, if you can, and paste link here. We need to see the binary content of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Are you holding entire content of a PDF in a DOM element attribute `this.getAttribute('data-pdffile')` ? This is where it may get corrupted.
2. When you call

   ```
   window.open(pdfvar, "_blank");
   ```

the content is not ready to be opened like that. It should be first converted to base64 encoded url.

```
window.open('data:application/pdf,' + escape(pdfvar));
```

**UPDATE:**

The actual problem was that the OP was trying to save the file using it's URL in "pdfvar"

```
fs.writeFile(filename, pdfvar);
```

but the file created was containing only a URL itself. What was required was downloading the file first using a http library:

- [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: 1.Im not holding entire content in the DOM.  Just the URL to the PDF file. That must be where Im going wrong.  How do I fix this?

Comment: 2.  Now I get, "Failed to load PDF document"  even when I am online.

Comment: @LeeTee so why do you pass URL to "saveFile" ? Then you will get fs.writeFile('test.pdf', 'http://address.com/file.pdf') The second parameter should be actual data not a URL. Your locally saved file is now a text file with just a URL inside...

Comment: What is your URL? Is it an absolute address with "http : //domain.com/files/file.pdf" or is it relative i.e. "files/file.pdf"? It should be absolute

Comment: yes its absolute.  OK so how do I get the data from the PDF file online to write it locally?  I couldnt find the info anywhere, hence why Ive done it wrong.  I thought I could simply download the PDF file and save it

Comment: @LeeTee use google, this is the first result for "node download url" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Thanks, thats what I need.  I didn't come across that, must have been searching with different keywords.