# How to use a download link to download a file with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to figure out how to use a download link to download a file in node.js. When I enter in the following link ([Download Subtitles for the Godfather](http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-19970c4c/sid-HDqJva1,GDzdHTtNtDXpgsv5ty1/file/1952184005)) into my web browser it will automatically download the file that contains the subtitles. How do I do this in node? And is there a way to name the file as I want it to be named as well as choose it's path? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944984/4258088

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for linking me to where it had already been answered!