# Want to transfer a piece of code from python to node using urllib

Tags: python, node.js, express

I have below code in python

```
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, basePath +ldnumber +".pdf")
```

I think what above code do is download data from given url and save it as second parameter "basePath + str(ldnumber)+".pdf".

I have written below code in node js to achieve same functionality:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream(basePath +ldnumber +".pdf");
   var request = http.get(URL, function(response)
   {
      response.pipe(file);
   });
```

But above code is just create a file for given basepath and not what I require to achieve.

Is there any way to download a file and save it on given destination path in node js.

*I am sure there must be some proper way but I am running little out of time so I am posting this question here till I find an answer to this.*

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have a url of image or PDF and I want to download it to given path. I referred this question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries' but got an error "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined". Can we use 'request' package of node to achieve this?