# Node: Get image from PDF whose URL has weird query string

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, npm, bots

As part of [#1917Live](https://twitter.com/hashtag/1917LIVE?src=hash), I've made a Twitter bot that tweets 100-year-old New York Times articles about Russia.

- [Link to repo](https://github.com/HarryStevens/nyt-1917)
- [Link to bot](https://twitter.com/nyt_1917)

It uses the New York Times' [Article Search API](https://developer.nytimes.com/article_search_v2.json) to get the articles and then uses [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) to tweet them.

I also try to make the tweets more engaging, like an actual newspaper would try to do. So I parse the headlines to make them more readable, tag users that are part of [#1917Live](https://twitter.com/hashtag/1917LIVE?src=hash), and add a hashtag.

Now here's the part where I'm stuck. Each article comes with a URL to a pdf file showing how it looked when it was printed. [Here's an example](http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF). I want to download that pdf, convert the first page into an image, and attach the image to the tweet. This is the simplified code I tried to use to get the PDF:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var url = "http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF";

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.pdf");
var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

But this does not work. If I were trying to download a normal pdf file, with a `.pdf` file extension, I suspect I wouldn't be having any problems. But this is different. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Try printing the error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134

Answer (score 0):

You can use YQL to get `JSON` result of query, get `"url"` property of `"result"` property of `"query"` property of `JSON` response which, if successful, will be `.pdf` file as a `data URI`

```js
let url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fquery.nytimes.com%2Fmem%2Farchive-free%2Fpdf%3Fres%3D9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF%22&format=json&callback=";

fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
.then(({query:{results:{url}}}) => console.log(url))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Note, the resource returns an `html` `document`, not a `.pdf` `document`. To get the URL of the `.pdf` at `html` `document`, set the `html` as `.innerHTML` of `<template>` element, then query `<iframe>` `.src`.

The URL at `<iframe>` also has an expires header, where `403 (Forbidden)` is returned as response after an as of yet unknown duration.

```js
let url = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fquery.nytimes.com%2Fmem%2Farchive-free%2Fpdf%3Fres%3D9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF%22&format=json&callback=";
let template = document.createElement("template");
fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
.then(({query:{results:{url}}}) => 
  fetch(url).then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => {
    template.innerHTML = html;     
    let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    let src = template.content.querySelector("iframe").src; 
    console.log(src);
    iframe.src = src.slice(0, src.indexOf("?"));
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  })
)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Note, the response from resource at `url` is `"text/html"` containing an `<iframe>` element which appears to render `.pdf` `document`.

Comment: It's logging `data:text/html;charset=UTF-8;base64` and then some really long string. What do I do with that? Also, if you try that URL here (https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), it returns an error.

Comment: The response from the resource is a `data URI` which is `"text/html"`, not `.pdf`. Within the `html` there is an `<iframe>` element, the `src` of `<iframe>` is set to `.pdf`. The `html` needs to be parsed for `<iframe>` `src`, though note, the URL does have an `"&Expires"` query string, though could probably be removed.

Comment: Did not get error here when tried at YQL. What was the query you tried?

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fquery.nytimes.com%2Fmem%2Farchive-free%2Fpdf%3Fres%3D9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF%22&format=json&callback=

Comment: There is an additional step necessary to get the URL of the `.pdf` from `<iframe>` within `html` string

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a much easier, and more obvious, way. I just used request and cheerio, as I should have done from the beginning.

```
var request = require("request"),
  cheerio = require("cheerio");

var url = "http://query.nytimes.com/mem/archive-free/pdf?res=9500E4DC153AE433A25756C1A9629C946696D6CF";

request(url, function(error, response, body){
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    var pdf = $("iframe").attr("src");
    console.log(pdf);
  }
});
```