# How to download audio file from URL in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio

How to download audio file from URL and store it in local directory?
I'm using Node.js and I tried the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var dest = 'C./test'
var url= 'http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/comic/comic002.wav'
function download(url, dest, callback) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function (response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function () {
      file.close(callback); // close() is async, call callback after close completes.
    });
    file.on('error', function (err) {
      fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
      if (callback)
        callback(err.message);
    });
  });
}
```

No error occured but the file has not been found.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually call the `download` function, so nothing is happening.

Comment: Why do you have `'` character before var and then the last line `}'` ?

Comment: None of the answers will work until those quotes are fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries), but here is the code specific to your question:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.wav");
var request = http.get("http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/comic/comic002.wav", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: @RajaSekar You're welcome! Please mark the answer as correct so other people know the question has been answered. :)

Comment: does `fs.createWriteStream("file.wav")` create a file on the server?  or does it just make it available to send back to client?

Comment: @user1063287 no, `fs.createWriteStream("file.wav")` does not create a file on the server. it opens a write stream to a file, which means that as bytes slowly come in from somewhere (the server), we have told the computer to let these bytes trickle into the hard drive _as they arrive_ (file.wav).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine, you just don't call the download function. Try adding this to the end :

```
download(url, dest, function(err){
   if(err){
     console.error(err);
   }else{
     console.log("Download complete");
   }
});
```

Also, change the value of `dest` to something else, like just `"test.wav"` or something. `'C./test'` is a bad path.

I tried it on my machine and your code works fine just adding the call and changing `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Axios with an API that may require authorization

```js
const Fs = require('fs');
const Path = require('path');
const Axios = require('axios');

async function download(url) {
    let filename = "filename";
    const username = "user";
    const password = "password"
    const key = Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString("base64");
    const path = Path.resolve(__dirname, "audio", filename)
    const response = await Axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        responseType: 'stream',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + key }
    })
    response.data.pipe(Fs.createWriteStream(path))
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        response.data.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
        })
        response.data.on('error', () => {
            reject(err);
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I tested this with several sources from [freesound.org](https://freesound.org), e.g. this one:
https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/512/512246_7704891-hq.mp3

```js
  public static async downloadAudio(audioSource: string, path: string) {
    const response = await axios.get(audioSource, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    });

    const arrayBuffer = response.data;
    const uintArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    const byteArray = Array.from(uintArray);
    const base64String = btoa(byteArray.map((char) => String.fromCharCode(char)).join(''));

    // choose an appropriate file writer here
    await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: path,
      data: base64String,
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      recursive: true,
    });
  }
```