# node.js How to use a url as pdf-path to work with pdf2json

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, pdf, pdf-parsing

I'm using node.js and pdf2json parser to parse a pdf file.
Currently it is working with a local pdf file.
But I'm trying to get a pdf-file through the URL/HTTP Module of node.js and I want to open this file to parse it.

Is there any possibility to parse/work with an online pdf?

```
let query   = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
let pdfLink = query.pdf;
...
pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfLink + "");
```

So the url should be given through the url like: https://localhost:8080/?pdf=http://whale-cms.de/pdf.pdf

Is there any way to parse it within the online pdf/link?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not to download it and work with it as a local file?

Comment: Because these pdfs on which were are working are updated every hour, so it would be much easier to do it over a url

Comment: Yes, just download it every time and work with it like a local file

Comment: It has to run by itself, it is saved in a database automatically

Comment: Download it automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 3):

Im just faced with the same problem, and found a solution:

```
        var request = require('request');
        var PDFParser = require("pdf2json");
        var pdfUrl = "http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/PDFFiles/sk87bAfiXxPre428b/original/sk87bAfiXxPre428b"
        var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

        var pdfPipe = request({url: pdfUrl, encoding:null}).pipe(pdfParser);

        pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataError", err => console.error(err) );
        pdfPipe.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdf => {
          let usedFieldsInTheDocument = pdfParser.getAllFieldsTypes();
            console.log(usedFieldsInTheDocument)
        });
```

Source from:
https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json/issues/65
Cheers

Comment: Please post your answer here, not just a link.

Comment: How to wait until pdfipe.on finishes execution in an async function??

Comment: @mayank1513 you can use await