# How to download image/s from cloudinary using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, cloudinary, imagedownload

Hi I'm working with cloudinary in my node.js project, and I have search a lot about how to download image/s from cloudinary to my server.

Is there anyone who knows how to do that ?

I didn't find this far a solution someone know how to do that ?

Comment: Cloudinary exposes an API: http://cloudinary.com/documentation So you can search images. Once you have the urls, you could download the files using node too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134/3244654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a successful upload, you'll get Cloudinary's [upload response](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#upload_response) which contains all necessary data to save on your end such as the resource's `public_id`, `version` for immediate cache busting. These parameters can be then used for further [manipulation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_manipulation#direct_url_building).

You also get the resource's `url` and `secure_url` (https) ready for delivery.

Comment: thanks but i use this. i not want to deliver it and just show it, i want to get the .jpg file to the storage

Comment: Then save the `url` - it's the image object.
If you want to download to your local storage, you can use the `attachment` flag in the URL.  For example,
http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_attachment/sample.jpg

Comment: In general, you don't need to save the url directly. You can generate it using the `public_id` (and `version` which is an optional parameter).

Comment: I want the image file in the server, not an url