# download file to local computer sent attatched to message discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

after looking on the Discord.js docs i can find an answer for the question, does someone know how to do it? theres already a question the page  but has no answers or comments.

imagine that someone on the chat sentí an image, is there a way of the bot downloading the image or get the url of the image?

thanks!

Comment: Guess you didn't look too far... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435819/reading-files-in-chat-using-discord-bot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters... You'd need the code to access the attachment.

```
client.on(`message`,function(msg){
    if(msg.attachments.first()){//checks if an attachment is sent
        if(msg.attachments.first().filename === `png`){//Download only png (customize this)
            download(msg.attachments.first().url);//Function I will show later
        }
    }
});
```

**Note:** I limited attachments to `png` only so we download verified images. Otherwise we might download some bad scripts and possibly viruses. Be careful when downloading stuff.

Now the code I just gave you calls `download` and passes in the `url`.
Now you will need the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module **AND** the [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs) module.

Why? Glad you asked... The `request` module accesses the url and pulls it the data from the web.
The `fs` module create/reads/writes files on your local/external machine...

Using the two modules, we will **pull it** and then **save it**.

Now lets assume `url` is this [meme.png](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/431142200991154178/472507594909679620/meme.png) (discord png attachment)

```
let request = require(`request`);
let fs = require(`fs`);
function download(url){
    request.get(url)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('meme.png'));
}
```

and **Voila!** We now have a `meme.png` image about Doritos XD

Answer (score 0):

Besides the link I posted in the comments section, from looking at the [Discord documentation](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#attachment-objecthttps://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#attachment-object), it appears the `url` is in the `attachment` object.

[image]