# Is it possible for my discord bot to download an image from the current chat to a directory on my pc?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So, here is what I envisioned, I made a simple message collector and I want the bot to collect files and then save them in its own folder, I am new to discord.js and I am most probably doing it wrong It would be of great help if I get an answer with some `code example`.

```
client.on('message', inspire);

function inspire(msg) {
    if (msg.content === '?create') {
        msg.channel.send('Inspire me...');

        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, filter);
        
        collector.on('collect', colMessage);
        function colMessage(msg) {
            console.log('Feeling inspired with ' + msg.content);
            if (msg.content === "?enough") {
                collector.stop();
            }

        }
        
        collector.on('end', overWith => {
            console.log('Was inspired by ' + overWith.size + ' messages');
            const painter = Math.floor(Math.random() * artists.length);
            msg.channel.send('Here is your ' + artists[painter] + ':');

            // Artist is an array of famous painters' names, which is just there for the bot to do a funny comparison of the image it is going to send back (which is a filtered version of the image I want to download) with a masterpiece.
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I figure I was not that clear, the thing here is that I am only collecting the message content but I want to also collect the msg.attachment, and then save it!  but I don't know how to do it :( :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [download file to local computer sent attatched to message discord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550993/download-file-to-local-computer-sent-attatched-to-message-discord)

Comment: Yes! jakye thank you very much!