# python 2.7 or javascript: Download a file from a download link using that has authentiation

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, authentication, download

I can't seem to find a source that does exactly what I want.

I have a website where there are download links, such that when I click one it downloads a pdf file. Also this website is password protected.

How in python 2.7 (not 3, because I use 2.7 for other stuff)  can I automatically download this file? All solutions I have seen either don't work or only work for a direct link to the file not a download link.

An alternative is javascript but then I would need to be able to rename the file or at least take a note of what the name is.

Please help

Comment: You can [download the file using Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries) or [using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python) or with any language that supports making HTTP requests.

Though I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "direct link" and "download link".

Comment: By direct linki  mean a Link that when I click it I see the file, and a download link is when I click it it downloads the file. (in download link it also downloads file if i copy and paste link into browser and hit enter.              The download link doesnt end in a .pdf even though it is a pdf