# How to download a file in the server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using node.js and express and I want to download a current file that is in a specific directory in my server side.

I tried as follows. There is no error but there is no file that is downloaded in my disk too.

What is my wrong?

```
app.get('/getFile', function(req, res){
  res.download('public/example.pem');
});
```

Also I tried that too

```
app.get('/getFile', function(req, res){
  var filename = path.basename('public/example.pem');

    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-pem-file');

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream('public/example.pem');
    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: seems like duplicated please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but the responses in there didn't work for me. Thank you @Ilan

Comment: ok. what about to serve the file as static resources? you can start from this option first...

Comment: I guess, you're right. I can serve the file as you mentioned