# Bot saving every image, gif or video sent in a specific channel on Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like my bot to save on my computer every image, video or even a gif that's sent in a specific channel. Is that possible to do?
I know that this kind of stuff can be made by fs directory but I'm not sure how would that code look like could you guys help me?

Answer (score 1):

To get all the images, gifs and videos from a message you can use the [`.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) property of a message. This will give you all the files from that message (if it contains files).

With this property you can create a loop where on every message send, you itterate through the `message.attachments` collection. Then, as stated by [the documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url), you can call the `.url` property on every attachment to get the link from which to download the file.

Once you have the link, you can follow [this answer from a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134/5793873) to download the file. Here's the code copied from the answer:

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
};
```

This means you will have to use the Node.js modules [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html). To use the code, the download method can be called like

```
download(<The file url to download>, <The file name you want to save it as>, <a callback function which can be called when an error occurs>);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code must help you,

```
import shutil
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

TOKEN = ""
prefix = "?"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
bot.run(TOKEN)
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("The message's content was", message.content)
    url = message.attachments[0]['url']
    if url[0:26] == "https://cnd.discordapp.com":
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(String.join(uuid.uuid4(),".png"), 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
```

use this and create a bot and install package requests, discord.py to run the bot.

Finally, add this bot to your channel and give it a bot role.

Comment: okey sorry for my unspecified question. I know how to make bot, im making this bot in discord.js and i just want a help with a code that will save every images videos and gifs in a folder in my computer. Javascript, not python

Comment: Okay sorry but i still need some help :D