# Open Puppeteer with specific configuration (download PDF instead of PDF viewer)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to open Chromium with a specific configuration.

I am looking for the configuration [to activate the following option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gJxe.png) :

Settings => Site Settings => Permissions => PDF documents => "Download PDF files instead of automatically openning them in Chrome"

I searched the tags on [this command line switch page](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but the only parameter that deals with pdf is `--print-to-pdf` which does not correspond to my need.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

There is no option you can pass into Puppeteer to force PDF downloads. However, you can use chrome-devtools-protocol to add a `content-disposition: attachment` response header to force downloads.

A visual flow of what you need to do:

[image: cdp-modify-response-header (2)]

I'll include a full example code below. In the example below, PDF files and XML files will be downloaded in headful mode.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null, 
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

  await client.send('Fetch.enable', {
    patterns: [
      {
        urlPattern: '*',
        requestStage: 'Response',
      },
    ],
  });

  await client.on('Fetch.requestPaused', async (reqEvent) => {
    const { requestId } = reqEvent;

    let responseHeaders = reqEvent.responseHeaders || [];
    let contentType = '';

    for (let elements of responseHeaders) {
      if (elements.name.toLowerCase() === 'content-type') {
        contentType = elements.value;
      }
    }

    if (contentType.endsWith('pdf') || contentType.endsWith('xml')) {

      responseHeaders.push({
        name: 'content-disposition',
        value: 'attachment',
      });

      const responseObj = await client.send('Fetch.getResponseBody', {
        requestId,
      });

      await client.send('Fetch.fulfillRequest', {
        requestId,
        responseCode: 200,
        responseHeaders,
        body: responseObj.body,
      });
    } else {
      await client.send('Fetch.continueRequest', { requestId });
    }
  });

  await page.goto('https://pdf-xml-download-test.vercel.app/');

  await page.waitFor(100000);

  await client.send('Fetch.disable');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

For a more detailed explanation, please refer to the [Git repo](https://github.com/subwaymatch/cdp-modify-response-example) I've setup with comments. It also includes an example code for [playwright](https://playwright.dev).

Comment: I've tried many solutions and only this work in my case, except `await page.goto` throws net::ERR_ABORTED error. By catching the error and just ignore it, and then verify the file in local path to confirm download succeed or not solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Puppeteer currently does not support navigating (or downloading) PDFs 
in headless mode that easily. Quote from the docs for the [`page.goto`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) function:

> **NOTE** Headless mode doesn't support navigation to a PDF document. See the [upstream issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=761295).

What you can do though, is detect if the browser is navigating to the PDF file and then download it yourself via Node.js.

**Code sample**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('request', req => {
        if (req.url() === '...') {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream('./file.pdf');
            http.get(req.url(), response => response.pipe(file));
        }
    });

    await page.goto('...');
    await browser.close();
})();
```

This navigates to a URL and monitors the ongoing requests. If the "matched request" is found, Node.js will manually download the file via `http.get` and pipe it into `file.pdf`. Please be aware that this is a minimal working example. You want to [catch errors when downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134/5627599) and might also want to use something more sophisticated then `http.get` depending on the situation.

#### Future note

In the future, there might be an easier way to do it. When puppeteer will support [response interception](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191), you will be able to simply [force the browser to download](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1248#issuecomment-341951692) a document, but right now this is not supported (May 2019).

Comment: Any chance you could revisit this if there is anything new to make it easier!