# have to download files from "Click Here" link which open the pdf on a separate window and then click on the save button to download file puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
    await page.goto('https://www.website.com/Dashboard.aspx');
```

// Dynamically adding IDs to get to required page

```
    await page.type('#searchBox_ID' ,ids.RequestID); 
    await page.click('#buttonCLick');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
```

// Now page has loaded

```
    await page.waitForSelector('#PdfFile_Selector');
    await page.click('#PdfFile_Selector');
```

// this will open the file in a new window and have to click on the download button on it
// how else can I do it ?

Comment: Does it work, like this?

Comment: Well it opens the link in a different window, but I am stuck how to move further, I am unable to click on the save button for the pdf file. @SilvanBregy

Comment: check this out => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254177/open-puppeteer-with-specific-configuration-download-pdf-instead-of-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 0):

According to the link i posted in the comment, i adapted this example on how to download a pdf. Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261960/8018716) for a more detailed explanation.

```
async function downloadPdf(page, url, targetFile, timeout_ms) {
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {

        // setup a timeout in case something goes wrong:
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            rej(new Error('Timeout after' + timeout_ms))
        }, timeout_ms)

        // the download listener:
        const listener = req => {

            console.log('on request!. url:', req.url())

            if (req.url() === url) {
                const file = fs.createWriteStream(targetFile);

                // clear timeout and listener
                page.removeListener('request', listener)
                clearTimeout(timeout)

                //@todo
                // add proper error handling here..
                http.get(req.url(), response => {

                    response.pipe(file).on('finish', () => {
                        res()
                    })
                });
            }

        }

        page.on('request', listener)

        // open the given url!.
        // either timeout or request listener will kick in.
        page.goto(url);

    })
}
```

And you could call it like this:

```
    // ...
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const url = 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf'
    const destFile = 'file.pdf'

    console.log('lets download', url)
    await downloadPdf(page, url, destFile, 20 * 1000)

    console.log('FIle should be downloaded under', destFile)
```

So when your pdf page has opened, copy it's url and open it in anther tab again  using `downloadPDF` function. Then close all tabs and you are done! .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't work for me though, So went around and used a different approach and got my task done. that procedure is not related to the question above so, not gonna comment it here. Thanks a bunch though.