# How to download a file from a url, without the involvement of browser in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to download a file from `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2018/QTR1/company.zip` and I want to specify a path for it to be saved on my computer, but I dont want to use any browser intermediate. Can someone guide me how to write a script in javascript to download the file from url and save it on my pc

Comment: You could use server-side code - I *believe* you can do it in Node, but that's a guess. Also, why don't you want to use the browser? You can write a script that takes a URL, and downloads the file for you. And there's `<a download>`...you have lots of options, but browsers are there and simple.

Comment: Ya I want to do it on Node only, Dont wanna use a browser...

Comment: This might help yoy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [chintuyadavsara said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404724/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-without-the-involvement-of-browser-in-javascr#comment99407669_56404724), filling in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries) with your url does the trick:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

function go (src, dest) {
    const file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    const request = https.get(src, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
    });
}

go('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2018/QTR1/company.zip', './company.zip');
```