# Why it is needed to invoke close after finish in nodejs stream?

Tags: node.js, stream

Here is a [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907134/1251549):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var download = function(url, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
};
```

Why `file.close(cb)` is called on `finish` event? Does not `finish` close a stream? Look strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before NodeJS version 5.5.0 it was the application's responsibility to close the file descriptor and make sure there's no file descriptor leak.

In v5.5 they introduced the `autoClose` attribute for the method `createWriteStream` with a default value of `true` which means on `error` or `finish` the file descriptor will be closed automatically.

The source you're looking at was before v5.5.0 (2016-01-21)