# How to download a file with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to download an image file with nodeJS, by using an API, but the problem is the API link doesn't have `.jpg` file in the end, how do I do,
below is how I am trying

```
url = 'https://i.pravatar.cc/225'
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs');


result = https.get(url, (resp) => {

        console.log('Result of response: ', resp)
        fs.writeFileSync('apiResponse', resp)
        console.log('Reached end!')
    })
```

When I click the URL it shows the image in browser, how do make my program to write the file on hard-drive,

Comment: There are many tutorials available for it. Ask if you face issue there

Comment: You should search before posting here, find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: I already searched before posting the question, but I was having problem in that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code uploads several different pictures

```
const url = 'https://i.pravatar.cc/225'

const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs');

for(let i=0; i<10; i++) 
  https.get(url, resp => resp.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./test_${i}.jpeg`)));
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, 
May I know the reason why it was not working when I simply put the code of your previous answer in a loop ?

Comment: Probably you declared variable `i` in loop as `var`

Comment: I didn't declared any type, just used `i` and it only downloaded the last image, not any other

Comment: but how are you declared this variable?

Comment: i didn't decleared any type, just used `i=0` but it was not working

Comment: yes, in this case `i` belongs global scope, but  you need declared via `let` for loop

Comment: so what if it belonged to global variables ?
the number value of `i` was successfully printing to console,

Comment: yes in case sync code, but `https.get` is async code

Comment: just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop

Answer (score 4):

Just pipe response to file

```
const url = 'https://i.pravatar.cc/225'

const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs');

https.get(url, resp => resp.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test.jpeg')));
```

Comment: Worked like magic, how did it worked ?, can you please explain a little

Comment: socket is stream, file is stream. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: I want to download the files in bulk quantity, using the same code, I tried to put the above snippet in a for loop but it always downloads the last file, what would be the problem ? I think it's related to async wait 
Can you guide me about that please

Answer (score 1):

please use this I have try with it and working fine you can rename the downloded file too.

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
const request = https.get("https://i.pravatar.cc/225", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Comment: alright, I've a slight different question, is there any way I can write the `resp` in a text file or any other format, I tried but it was only showing [object object] but when i console logged it, it was a huge object

Answer (score -2):

Try `download-file` library

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-file
```

Install : `npm install download-file --save`

```
var download = require('download-file')

var url = "http://i.imgur.com/G9bDaPH.jpg"

var options = {
    directory: "./images/cats/",
    filename: "cat.gif"
}

download(url, options, function(err){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("meow")
})
```