# Error handling fs.createWriteStream on read-only file?

Tags: node.js, fs

On Windows if I create a file and add the read-only attribute, and then make this call:

```js
console.log('a');
let fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('D:\\read-only-file.txt');
console.log('b');
console.log('c');
```

I see this in the Chrome console:

```
a
b
Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\read-only-file.txt'
c
```

But is there a way to actually catch this error? If I go on to try and use the file write stream anyway (i.e. pipe with http) it doesn't actually do anything. If I add this handler:

```js
fileWriteStream.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('in error...');
});
```

The error handler is not called. It is like this read-only exception is internally orphaned. Is there a way to handle this failure?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you say in node v14.4.0.  When I add `fileWriteStream.on('error', ...)`, that error event IS emitted when the file is read-only.  What version of node.js are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks jfriend00, I continued to work at it as you mentioned you got it to work, and I got it to work also. My problem was I was following the pattern outlined in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17676794/5988923

The issue is the `.on('error')` and `.on('finish')` were registered *after* the call to `pipe`. I just changed it to register the events immediately after creating the write stream. Now it all works.

Thanks!