# How to fetch a file with its name (located with in a folder in local machine) and download it in browser with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, fs

How do I fetch a file from local machine with its file name and dowloand the same in Node.js without using third-party libraries?

I have seen this answer similar to this - [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

but it shows to download using URL, but I need to fetch and download from my local, is it possible ?

node version I'm using is - **6.10.0**

Comment: is fs what you're looking for? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html you already tagged your question with it so is there something else?

Comment: I'm using the older version of node - 6.10.0,  will it work with the link you sent?

Comment: Yes, fs has been part of node from the start. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/fs.html

Comment: Confused.  Are you asking how to send a file using your browser from the browser's local hard disk to your server? Or are you asking how your server can fetch a file directly from a remote computer with no browser involved?

Comment: fetch a file directly and download it in a browser

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need "download" from your "local" - you're there already no?
If you need to read from your local in order to process or move it somewhere look at the File System module
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

```
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
```

then you can do something with that file like upload it elsewhere

```
s3.upload({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: fileStream});
```

hth