# How to get picture sent in message? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have script in discord.js to send `message.content` and `message.attachments` eg. picture from user in bot message.

Script:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    message.channel.send({
         "embed": {
            "color": 14680086,
            "description": message.content + message.attachments,
            "author": {
                "icon_url": "url to some picture",
                "url": "url to some picture",
                "name": "some text"
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Bot sends `message.content` but when I add a picture I get `[object Map]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`message.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) is a discord collection, so you can't add it to embed description.
The one way to do it, it check if message has attachment, then add it into `embed.image`

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    let messageAttachment = message.attachments.size > 0 ? message.attachments.array()[0].url : null
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
        if (messageAttachment) embed.setImage(messageAttachment)
        embed.setColor(14680086)
        await message.channel.send(embed)
        message.delete()
})
client.login(token)
```

Comment: I have one more question. How in this case I can delete user message. Because when i add message.delete at the end bot send empty message.
Something like this:
1. User send message
2. Bot send user message in embed
3. Bot delete user message

Comment: If you delete user message with image, image will deleted too, so you need yo save image to local storage and then use it in embed.

Comment: How can i save image in local storage in this case?

Comment: You can use [download-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-file) as varian. Or use http and pipe [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)