# Is there a way to provide file for download using only Node without using express like below?

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){

  const file = `${__dirname}/upload-folder/dramaticpenguin.MOV`;
  
res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: @Sebastian Kaczmarek. No actually I want to provide a way to user to download file when he clicks at link in html page. this code downloads the file for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simple example that should give you a start on how to implement this without express:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const httpServer = http.createServer(requestResponseHandler);    

function requestResponseHandler(req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/download') {
    const file = `${__dirname}/sample-video.mov`;
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'video/quicktime',
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="sample.mov',
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(res);
  }
}

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Basically all it does is to set the correct `content-type` and `content-disposition` headers and the create a read-stream from the `mov`-file and pipe this stream into the response-object.