# NodeJS - How to get response of URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I have an url adress. When I go that adress in browser it shows a json file. I need to get that json file in NodeJs.

How can I do that?

Edit: This is my current code:

```
const got = require('got');   

var url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1";  

got(url).json().then(result => {     
    console.log(result); 
}).catch(err => {     
    console.log(err); 
});
```

And This is the result I get:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Hint: hit control+c anytime to enter REPL.
RequestError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/%3F__a%3D1"
    at Object.parseBody [as default] (/home/runner/VengefulUltimateSdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/parse-body.js:22:15)
    at /home/runner/VengefulUltimateSdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/index.js:157:40
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJson (/home/runner/VengefulUltimateSdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/index.js:118:35)
    at Object.parseBody [as default] (/home/runner/VengefulUltimateSdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/parse-body.js:11:48)
    at /home/runner/VengefulUltimateSdk/node_modules/got/dist/source/as-promise/index.js:157:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  name: 'ParseError',
  code: undefined,
  timings: {
    start: 1601274389096,
    socket: 1601274389096,
    lookup: 1601274389106,
    connect: 1601274389117,
    secureConnect: 1601274389128,
    upload: 1601274389128,
    response: 1601274389467,
    end: 1601274389511,
    error: undefined,
    abort: undefined,
    phases: {
      wait: 0,
      dns: 10,
      tcp: 11,
      tls: 11,
      request: 0,
      firstByte: 339,
      download: 44,
      total: 415
    }
  }
}
```

My node version is 12.16.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

Comment: @tomerpacific no it doesnt work for me. I cant get json .

Comment: @UzaySan what do you mean it doesn't work? There are a ton of answers on that post. How many have you tried? I don't think many, coz you replied after a mere 3 minutes after that link was shared.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Yes bunch of answers but they all suggest using http library. And When I use that method, I get response headers. not the actual json.

Comment: Do you want to write this to a file?

Comment: @SridharChidurala No ı dont want to write it to a file. I need to extract few objects. and thats it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it as json you can use the fetch api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) then in the promises you can read the json as an object in your js code.

```
fetch('http://server/file.json').then(resp=>resp.json()).then(data=>{do something with data});
```

Comment: `fetch()` works in the browser.  The OP asked for a solution in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can either parse the JSON yourself or you can get a library for making an Http request that parses the JSON automatically for you.  There are lots of libraries to choose from [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) and it will let you parse the JSON with a simple `.json()` added to it so the resolved value you get back is a Javascript object.

```
const got = require('got');

got("https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1").json().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I run the above code with your [instagram URL](https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1), I get this Javascript object back:

```
{
  graphql: {
    shortcode_media: {
      __typename: 'GraphSidecar',
      id: '2404017227651993316',
      shortcode: 'CFcyO54Hc7k',
      dimensions: [Object],
      gating_info: null,
      fact_check_overall_rating: null,
      fact_check_information: null,
      sensitivity_friction_info: null,
      media_overlay_info: null,
      media_preview: null,
      display_url: 'https://scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/119980944_890957481429986_8757958615208227911_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=w7zBW_FdRNgAX9BYknl&_nc_tp=18&oh=11424efc118b55180e4d3302d75181ca&oe=5F99EB23',
      display_resources: [Array],
      is_video: false,
      tracking_token: 'eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiZGIyMzdkMzgzYWVhNDY5YmI0ZWVkZWI4YzlhZDY0YWUyNDA0MDE3MjI3NjUxOTkzMzE2In0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9',
      edge_media_to_tagged_user: [Object],
      edge_media_to_caption: [Object],
      caption_is_edited: false,
      has_ranked_comments: false,
      edge_media_to_parent_comment: [Object],
      edge_media_to_hoisted_comment: [Object],
      edge_media_preview_comment: [Object],
      comments_disabled: false,
      commenting_disabled_for_viewer: false,
      taken_at_timestamp: 1600801207,
      edge_media_preview_like: [Object],
      edge_media_to_sponsor_user: [Object],
      location: null,
      viewer_has_liked: false,
      viewer_has_saved: false,
      viewer_has_saved_to_collection: false,
      viewer_in_photo_of_you: false,
      viewer_can_reshare: true,
      owner: [Object],
      is_ad: false,
      edge_web_media_to_related_media: [Object],
      edge_sidecar_to_children: [Object],
      edge_related_profiles: [Object]
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you'd rather modify your existing code, then you will probably need to use `JSON.parse()`.  You will have to add your existing code to your question for us to help with that.

Comment: I don't want to write file. I need to extract few objects in it and save it to database. I guess i need to explain. This is my url: `https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1` I want to get json from this url. When I go to this url in browser it shows json file. But ın node js, ıt just returns html with javascript methods. I tried request library. But I guess I need to add session token header.

Comment: I also mention that, when I use request library with other url like `reddit.com/popular.json` It returns json. So I guess my problem is with instagram. But I dont know How to solve it

Comment: @UzaySan - My mistake.  I left a `.json()` out of my code which I have now added.  When I insert that, your instagram URL gives me a nice Javascript object.  In the future, please include things like a specific URL in your question so people can test out their answers against your actual situation.

Comment: I tried latest code. I get this error. `RequestError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/%3F__a%3D1" ` I think I need to add a session token. How can I add this? Or how to solve this? Edit: I see you added a perfect json file. I cant get that. I'm using repl.it online node editor.

Comment: @UzaySan - When I plug your instagram URL into my code above, I get the Javascript object now shown in my answer.  Is that not what you want? Please note that the %3F and %3D should not be in your URL.  That indicates something was encoding the ? and the = and should not have been doing that.  You need to real characters in the URL.

Comment: That chars are not in my URL. This is my URL: `https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1` I think instagram redirects. But I dont know why.   This is my full code:    `const got = require('got');


var url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1";

got(url).json().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});`

Comment: @UzaySan - And, what exactly is the result you get?  What version of node.js?  What version of got?

Comment: I have edited my question. I added my current code, node version and result I get. Please take a look

Comment: @UzaySan - I don't know what to say.  The same code works just fine for me in node `v14.10.0` and I'm using got 11.7.0 which is current.  Are you running this in REPL or running it from a file via the command line.  I'm running it from a file via the command line.  I never use REPL as I've found too many differences between it and real nodejs.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'm using this code in repl online editor. I didnt use it with command line. I will try it in server to see i it makes any difference. Thanks again

Comment: @UzaySan - Did it work in a regular node.js script file?

Comment: I didnt try actually. I found a npm module that does exactly what I want. I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axios in NodeJS.

```
axios.get('https://someapiendpoint.domain.com/v1/api')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
```

Comment: I tried axios. But getting same result. `https://www.instagram.com/p/CFcyO54Hc7k/?__a=1` doesnt return a json. But in browser it shows a json.

Comment: You cannot access Instagram APIs directly as Instagram Legacy API permission was disabled on June 29, 2020 in favor of new Instagram graph API. You can try the wrapper https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-graph-sdk