# How can I allow users download files using node js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, download

I am creating a website for my school and I want to allow the students to be able to download files (pdfs)
using node js. So basically, they would see a bunch of different links and when they click any link the downloading would start.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: So the download should be done via a backend NodeJS service and not directly from the web page using an URL pointing to the file location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this `express` so I'm going to assume you already have express installed via npm. I'm also going to assume the files you want are in the `downloads` directory in that folder. Express actually has a `res.download` module, too, so I used that in this simple example:

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
app.get("/downloads/:file", (req, res) => {
  res.download(
    path.join(__dirname, "downloads/" + req.params.file),
    (err) => {
      if (err) res.status(404).send("<h1>Not found: 404</h1>");
    }
  );
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/downloads/file1.pdf">
        file1.pdf
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/downloads/file2.pdf">
        file2.pdf
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/downloads/file3.pdf">
        file3.pdf
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>`);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

So when a user goes to `http://localhost:3000/downloads/file.pdf`, Express will send the file to download in `./downloads/file.pdf`