# Upload file to google cloud storage use link

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage

I try to upload a file from the link to GCS but I don't know how to do it,

This is my code

```
app.post("/uploads", upload.any("tmparr"), async (req, res) => {
  await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .upload(
      "https://lalalai.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/media/split/9f6f7cb6-43b2-45ee-bec7-16ae2f7214b5/vocals",
      {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: {
          cacheControl: "public, max-age=31536000",
        },
      }
    );
  console.log("done");
});
```

I got an error like this

```
(node:56016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\reactjs\crud-mern\server\https:\lalalai.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\media\split\9f6f7cb6-43b2-45ee-bec7-16ae2f7214b5\vocals'
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:56016) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This 
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:56016) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the 
Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can someone help me to fix it? thank you

Comment: if you look on the path, it's trying to grab the file from your local machine

Comment: yeah I know, but how to grab the file from the link?

Comment: fetch the file with nodejs, and then put it on gcs

Comment: can you give me an example? I'm new in javascript @MehdiBenmoha

Comment: yes sure, welcome to javascript world, here's the example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: thank you, can I upload the file to GCS without download the file? @MehdiBenmoha

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage does not accepts a url link to a file as a parameter for upload, as you can see in the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) for `bucket.upload()` it requires:

> The fully qualified path to the file you wish to upload to your bucket.

And the error message you get is proof of this, since it tries to interpret the URL as a path on your local system.

So in order to make this work you have to first download said file from the link and only then call for the GCS SDK and upload it.