# Using AWS download presigned URL in Node to transfer file to AWS bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am currently working on an integration between Hover and my app. I have most of the nuts and bolts figured out but I cannot get the images portion figured out. The specific API I am trying to dial in can be found here:

https://developers.hover.to/?shell#images

I am trying to get the file object using the above api and immediately upload the object to my S3 instance. I have this workflow set up already for the following two API's which would make me believe the images would be straight forward but it is not working as these are:

https://developers.hover.to/?shell#job-exports

https://developers.hover.to/?shell#get-a-job-39-s-measurements

With the last two API's I am able to grab the file object and upload them to s3 as expected but this same workflow is not working with the images API above.

Here is the function I am running currently to get the images and upload them to my s3 (again same workflow is working for the two other API's).

```
const url = `${hoverBaseURL}/api/v2/images/${imageId}/rotated_image.jpg`;
    
const response = await hoverAPI.get(url);

const name = `${imageId}_${customerId}.jpg`;

const key = `${_id}/activities/${name}`;

await s3
  .putObject({
    Bucket: keys.awsBucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: response.data,
    ContentType:"image/jpeg",
    ACL: "public-read",
  })
  .promise();
```

The `hoverApi` is simply an axios instance with the proper Authorization headers added.

This creates an object in the AWS s3 bucket but it is not the image as expected and is instead a small white square in the middle of the screen (see the image below).

Here are the headers that are returned when I run `hoverAPI.get(url)` above:

```
Date: Sun, 31 Jul 2022 18:44:36 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 2036519
Connection: keep-alive
CF-Ray: 73387c82689381d0-IAD
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 243
ETag: "c9e13d8f9260ae98838bd0338c3de12d"
Last-Modified: Sun, 31 Jul 2022 02:55:04 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0
CF-Cache-Status: HIT
Cf-Bgj: imgq:100,h2pri
Cf-Polished: origSize=2201380, status=webp_bigger
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
x-amz-id-2: K6V7VmCsZirLp/GmfgZ18SAd4AnA/Yy1yqZkuZi5eD4I3wzeVwIb+7RASkoL2xqQFPkW79zgJz8=
x-amz-request-id: K9PGT6X9B5VTQ42H
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
x-amz-version-id: HBcjh5F..h3WHSZImSloMlO__RrHDQDy
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
```

Image being saved to s3:
[image]

Image logged out in my Node server:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below worked for me:

```
const downloadFile = async (downloadUrl: string): Promise<any> => {
  return axios.get(downloadUrl, {
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
};

const uploadFromStream = (
  fileResponse: AxiosResponse,
  fileName: string,
  bucket: string,
): { passThrough: PassThrough; promise: Promise<S3.ManagedUpload.SendData> } => {
  const s3 = new S3();
  const passThrough = new PassThrough();
  const promise = s3
    .upload({
      Bucket: bucket,
      Key: fileName,
      ContentType: fileResponse.headers['content-type'],
      ContentLength: fileResponse.headers['content-length'],
      Body: passThrough,
    })
    .promise();
  return { passThrough, promise };
};

export const handler = async (event: CopyFileEvent): Promise<string> => {
  const responseStream = await downloadFile(event.fileUrl);

  const { passThrough, promise } = uploadFromStream(responseStream, event.fileName, 'test-bucket');

  responseStream.data.pipe(passThrough);

  return promise
    .then((result) => {
      return result.Location;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
};
```

Credit to:
https://dev.to/vikasgarghb/streaming-files-to-s3-using-axios-h32