# How to automate downloads with chromedriver + selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Node.js file that looks like this:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().setUserPreferences(
    { "download.default_directory": dir.join(__dirname, 'extensions')}
  ))
  .build();

driver.get("[URL to Download]")
```

When I run this, it downloads the item I want, but chrome warns that the file might not be safe:
[image]

Is there Any way to automatically accept the download or click continue?

Comment: Is the objective to just download files locally? There are other ways to do this without chrome.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  yes, when I navegate to the url, it downloads it, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I googled and found this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `download.prompt_for_download` preference available for Chrome. Try adding it

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(new chrome.Options().setUserPreferences(
    { "download.default_directory": dir.join(__dirname, 'extensions'),
      "download.prompt_for_download": false
    }
  ))
  .build();
```