# throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js

I've tried multiple solutions coming from: [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)

I have the following path related error:

```
internal/streams/legacy.js:57
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'bot_side/img/image.jpg'
```

My app structure looks like this:
[image]

My code is the following:

```
download(url, path, () => {
      return imageClassification(path)
})

const download = (url, path, callback) => {
  request.head(url, (err, res, body) => {
    request(url)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
      .on('close', callback)
  })
}
```

Thanks.