# NodeJS download speeds signifcantly slower than Chrome

Tags: node.js, https, http2

I have been experiencing slower than expected downloads in a simple nodejs app.

I am testing by downloading a 350MB file from a Digital Ocean bucket.

My code is copied directly from here, though I have tried with the https module as well, with the same result:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65169393

I am consistently getting speeds of ~200KB/s.
On the same device, in chrome, the same file downloads at 10MB/s.

According to googles speed test, my internet is currently sitting at 100MB/s.

What would be a good way of debugging this?
I cannot find how this code could be further simplified.
Are there default settings in node or the https/http2 modules that I am missing?